# How to create more than one bean in one configuration class in spring using annotation and how to use those bean ?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, configuration-files

How to create more than one bean in one configuration class in spring using annotation @Configuration and how to use those bean ?

Answer (score -1):

You could use `@scope("prototype")` annotation after `@configuration` to ensure you have multiple instances of the same bean.

You could use the same bean by autowiring like:

```
//class
@Autowired
private MyBean myBean;
```

or better you could use like:

```
//MyConstructor class
@Autowired
MyConstructor (MyBean myBean) {
   ...
}
```

I'm assuming you would need multiple instances of `MyConstructor` too.

If you need to create multiple beans within same class you could do something like:

```
@Bean
@scope("prototype")
public MyBean getMyBean() {
    //.....
}
.....
@Bean
@scope("prototype")
public MyBean2 getMyBean2() {
    //.....
}
```

And you could still use `@Autowired` annotation as explained above.

Comment: `prototype` is irrelevant here. You created 2 beans with different names, which could be done with singleton just fine.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Did you see they are two different beans defined see the return type? What were you expecting.. i hope you are not friend of OP where you know everything that OP is expecting? If you know the requirements speak out clearly rather than pinpointing.

Comment: I saw that they are beans of different type, and that has nothing to do with prototype scope, which is used for creating a new instance on *every* invocation. As for the requirements, I don't think there are any, other than babysitting. The OP didn't show any discernible effort on his part, he didn't even bother to provide a clear use case. You took the time to post an answer, which I thought was kind considering his post, but doesn't mean I've to agree with it. So, we are having a conversation.